# Retrive data of address book and display in string format

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

Hi I am developing an apps in that I got one requirement where I have a button action method when I click the button I should retrive whole address book contacts and display in the form of string how do i do this can anyone tel me with code. I am not able to this from couple of days.

I **dont want** to navigate using **`ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`** and access it
,What all I need is click on button access all contact and display in the form of string.

Comment: Pl use search. `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople` is what you need.

Comment: ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( );
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );

for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ )
{
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );
    ...
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it works for **iOS 6 as well as iOS 5.0 or older**:

First add the following frameworks in **Link Binary With Libraries**

- **AddressBookUI.framework**
- **AddressBook.framework**

Them Import

```
#import <AddressBook/ABAddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
```

Then use the following code

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

__block BOOL accessGranted = NO;

if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // We are on iOS 6
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        accessGranted = granted;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    });

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_release(semaphore);
}

else { // We are on iOS 5 or Older
    accessGranted = YES;
    [self getContactsWithAddressBook:addressBook];
}

if (accessGranted) {
    [self getContactsWithAddressBook:addressBook];
}

// Get the contacts.
- (void)getContactsWithAddressBook:(ABAddressBookRef )addressBook {
    NSArray *arrayOfPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

    NSUInteger index = 0;
    NSMutableArray *firstNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(index = 0; index <= ([arrayOfPeople count] - 1); index++){
        ABRecordRef currentPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)[arrayOfPeople objectAtIndex:index];
        NSString *currentFirstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(currentPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

        // If first name is empty then don't add to the array
        if (![currentFirstName length] == 0) {
            [firstNames addObject: currentFirstName];
        }

    }
    //OPTIONAL: Use the following line to sort the first names alphabetically
    NSArray *sortedFirstNames = [firstNames sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSLog(@"Total Count = %d \n Sorted By Name = %@", [sortedFirstNames count], sortedFirstNames);
}
```

I tested this and it works.

Answer (score 0):

try this for .

```
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    NSArray *people = (NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    for(id person in people){
         NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue( person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty ),(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue( person, kABPersonLastNameProperty )];
    //fetch multiple phone nos.
        ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        for (CFIndex j=0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(multi); j++) {
            NSString* phone = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, j);
            [numbersArray addObject:phone];
            [phone release];
        }

          /fetch multiple email ids.
        ABMultiValueRef multiemail = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        for (CFIndex j=0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(multiemail); j++) {
             NSString* email = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiemail, j);
             NSLog(@"Email=%@",email);
        }
    }
```

and you have to alloc your array before you use. in viewDidLoad method write this for alloc array

```
           numbersArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```